# Conditional breakpoint in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

Can I have a conditional breakpoint in visual studio?
For example, I want the run to break in case a boolean value is changed to true.
Can I do it? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure
You have to set breakpont and right click on it. From context menu choose "Condition..." and type your variable name there. And select "Is true". In condition field you can write an expression like in `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks. My question is if I can do it without setting a breakpoint in a specific place (for example, a boolean can get changed in 100 different places), and I want the debug to stop in the place it get changed, without setting 100 breakpoints.